# React Fx.render performance in Diffing Algorithm

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im talking about Reconciliation in reactJS

i read this section on React Documentation , react said -> When diffing two trees, React first compares the two root elements. The behavior is different depending on the types of the root elements.

you can read this section ( https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm)

now for check this, i create a codePen and implement two tree node element for render function in my component and also create a Button Tag for toggle between

one render function have DIV tag for root of tree-node

```
render() { 
   return(<div> <h1> A element </h1> </div> );
 }
```

and the other is a SPAN tag

```
render() { 
   return(<span> <h1> B element </h1> </span> );
 }
```

react in this situation ( i read in React document ) , when component will update || change State , React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch. and When tearing down a tree, old DOM nodes are destroyed this lifecycle method fire

```
componentWillMount()
componentDidMount()
componentWillUnmount()
```

the last method happen because tearing down a tree and tree node destroyed

now i create this code pen and log in console when this function fired
i toggle state and update component with different root element for render method , but just this method fired => componentWillUpdate()

why ? please say me , and help me about this performance case or give me some link or article , thanks

code in this address . plz check console https://codepen.io/hamidrezanikoonia/pen/QmapEV?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

for this situation , when you have Custom Component in render , and your Custom Component wrap with root element , for example

```
<div> 
    <MyComponent />
</div>
```

and the other is

```
<span>
  <MyComponent />
</span>
```

now if u set this life-cycle method inside  
you can see when change State and Update your Parent Component

```
   componentWillUnmount()
```

happen